# How to fix linker error " Undefined symbols for architecture i386 from:     "_current_task" "?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, task

In kern/task.h, i found the declare:

```
__BEGIN_DECLS
extern task_t current_task(void);
extern void task_reference(task_t task); 
__END_DECLS
```

But when i call the function current_task() in an **iOS application**.
I got the linker error like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386 from:
"_current_task", referenced from:.... in xxx.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution:
    Use mach_task_self() to replace the function current_task. Still could returns a pointer to the task structure associated with the currently running kernel thread.

But i still want solve the problem above.:(